# More Effective way of picking a part a String from JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, stringbuilder, jtextpane

It's not that my code doesn't work, but I am doubting whether it's very efficient or not. My theory is, that it isn't xD

I have a JTextPane where I have to take the text in it (Making a new line every time the JTextPane got a new line basically), and put it into a .txt file. As I said everything works but I am doubting the implementation of it.
This is the part I am doubting:

```
public void printLog() {
    String s = logTextArea.getText();
    ArrayList<String> log = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != '\n') {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            log.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }
    }
```

This is the entire thing just for reference:

```
public void printLog() {
    String s = logTextArea.getText();
    ArrayList<String> log = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != '\n') {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            log.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }
    }
    File f = new File("JServer_Log.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fr = null;
    try {
        if(f.exists()) {
            fr = new FileWriter(f,true);
        } else {
            fr = new FileWriter(f);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Nothing to do really.
    }

    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fr);
        Iterator<String> itr = log.iterator();
        bw.newLine();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            bw.write(itr.next());
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Nothing to do really. We lost the log?
    } finally {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            // The program is closing any way.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just need to make sure you use the platform's appropriate newline sequence. You can just say `s = s.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))` and then write that whole string directly to file. In fact, the way I see it, this is all the code you need (except maybe for exception handling, up to you):

```
public void printLog() throws IOException {
  final FileWriter w = new FileWriter("JServer_Log.txt", true);
  try {
    w.write(logTextArea.getText().replace("\n", 
                                    System.getProperty("line.separator")));
  } finally { w.close(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks more elegant if anything at least xD

Answer (score 2):

For information, the first code can be replaced by:

```
List<String> log = Arrays.asList(logTextArea.getText().split("\n"));
```

but other answers give you a way to replace the whole method.

Answer (score 2):

Why bothering, to use [JTextComponents.write(Writer out) throws IOExceptionwrite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) this is pretty accepting newline, tabs, e.i. that came from Native OS

Comment: I am not using a JTextArea. I am using a JTextPane.

Comment: Plus, a `Writer` handles text encoding, but not newlines, as far as I know. That's why we need to use the `...Line` methods.

Comment: @both amended JTextArea to JTextComponent, did you tried, both read() and write() to take/add String from/to Document (model for JTextComponents)

Comment: `PrintWriter` has a `printline()` that uses `line.separator`.

Answer (score 0):

use `split`:

```
String[] log = s.split("\n");
```